# What is Angular's Custom Module lifecycle?

Tags: angular, angular2-modules, angular2-injection

Is there information about a Module's lifecycle. Currently the lifecycle of Components inside Angular is well documented and we have hook methods like `ngOnInit()`, `ngDoCheck()`, etc.

Do we have similar lifecycle hooks for Angular Modules? Where can I read something about this?